# Error with inserting to DB

Tags: php, mysql

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in Z:\home\ser.ser\www\sign_up.php on line 19

Also I have error with `$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (login="$login")");`

Help, please.

```
<?php
        include 'mysql_connect.php';

        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $b_arr['b_dd'] = $_POST['B_DD'];
        $b_arr['b_mm'] = $_POST['B_MM'];
        $b_arr['b_yy'] = $_POST['B_YY'];
        $b_date = $b_arr['b_yy'].$$b_arr['b_mm'].$b_arr['b_dd'];
        if (!isUserExist($login)) {
            reg($login, $password, $b_date);
        } else {
            echo 'This user is exist !';
        }
        function reg($login, $password, $b_date) {
           // NEXT LINE ERROR
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ("$login", "$password", "$b_date")");
           // END ERROR
        }
        function isUserExist($login) {
            $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (login="$login")");
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($q);
            if ($result) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You have numerous typos throughout that code. `$$b_arr`?

Comment: well @MarcB that answer below seems to not think so. `$$b_arr['b_mm'].$b_arr['b_dd'];` - are answers truly solutions? *hm...*

Comment: @MarcB No matter the sadness, unfortunately that's valid variable declaration. PHP won't yell at Sergey for it.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus still a low-quality answer though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't provide any answers...

Comment: by why a var-var in one case, and plain var the other? I'm betting on typo. especially with the bad `"`-string syntax later on.

Comment: @MarcB I do agree that it's 99.999% likely a typo

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I know and I do know that you don't provide low-quality answers, which is what I edited in my comment below ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning: this code is dangerous.** Please read about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and why your code is extremely problematic. In short, anything that's put into the database **must be sanitized**.

Now, more to your question:

You aren't handling strings correctly. If you wish to use this dangerous method of querying, you need to concatenate your values into a string. To add variables to a string you use the `.` operator. So, to fix this line you would need to use something like:

```php
$qry_str = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('" . $login . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $b_date . "')";
$query = mysql_query($qry_str);
```

Note: I broke it into two lines for better readability and your `isUserExist()` function has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in concatenations.
Please look at here: https://www.diffnow.com/?report=jgv1m

```
<?php
        include 'mysql_connect.php';

        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $b_arr['b_dd'] = $_POST['B_DD'];
        $b_arr['b_mm'] = $_POST['B_MM'];
        $b_arr['b_yy'] = $_POST['B_YY'];
        $b_date = $b_arr['b_yy'].$$b_arr['b_mm'].$b_arr['b_dd'];
        if (!isUserExist($login)) {
            reg($login, $password, $b_date);
        } else {
            echo 'This user is exist !';
        }
        function reg($login, $password, $b_date) {
// NEXT LINE ERROR
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('".$login."', '".$password."', '".$b_date."')");
// END ERROR
        }
        function isUserExist($login) {
            $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (login='".$login."')");
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($q);
            if ($result) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Might be useful to point out the inevitable future-line error as well :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus *ahem*... I upvoted your comment here, that's what I was talking about up there ;-) and I know you don't give low-quality answers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks! Cheers

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I edited the answer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You're quite welcome ;-) *Cheers!*